# Webservice and ORM Framework?

Tags: php, c++, web-services, soap, frameworks

Does anybody know a good web framework that includes an ORM mapper and allows straight forward implementation of web services? I'm looking for a framework written in PHP or C++. I'm looking for the following features (not all of them required, *some* will do nicely)

- data definition in one place used by database and web service
- WSDL generation
- XML output/JSON output
- boilerplate code generation

So what I would like is a framework that let's me specify the objects, the web service functions on those objects and then generate everything that is required leaving me to fill the business logic (connecting the database to the web service).

Anything like that out there?

Background information for why I need this:

I'm looking into creating a web project: the client is a rich web application that fetches *all* its data using AJAX. It will be completely custom made using only a low level javascript library. The server back end is supposed to serve static content and javascript (basically the rich web application) and to provide a RESTful web service API (which I would like to implement using aforementioned framework).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using [Zend_Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) and replacing Zend_Db with [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) as your ORM.

You can use Zend_Service to consume webservices and Zend_Rest_Controller to serve a REST API.

There are some good screencasts on integrating Doctrine and Zend [here](http://www.zendcasts.com/tag/doctrine/).  If you have alot of PHP experience, it shouldn't take very long to integrate. I believe there are even some sample integrations on Github.

Comment: I know ZEND quite well but have never used doctrine. I will give it a try, thanks!